# Spanning trees of specific graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let H be graph obtained from $G$ by replacing every edge by path of length $k$. Find number of spanning trees of graph $t(H)$ in terms of number of spanning trees of $t(G)$.

I noticed if $G$ is tree then $H$ is also tree and $t(H)=t(G)$. I tried to find that number based on number of cycles in graph but that didn't help.

Update $1$: Recursive formula crossed my mind
$t(G)=t(G\cdot e)+t(G-e)$

Update $2$: I know answer if $G$ cycle because then $H$ will be also cycle and then $t(H)$ will just be length of cycle

Update $3$: If $G$ is tree then $H$ is also tree so in that case $t(G)=t(H)$

Comment: Are $t(G)$ and $t(H)$ the number of spanning trees in $G$ and $H$ respectively?

Comment: If I give you a spanning tree $T$ of $G$, can you find some spanning trees of $H$ that "look like" $T$?

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe I can only think of one such as that

Comment: What if $G=K_3$ (on vertex set $\{1,2,3\}$), $k=3$, and $E(T)=\{12,13\}$? What is the one spanning tree of $H$ you can think of that look likes $T$?

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe If you give me $T$, then I can think of one and it is path of length $8$ that goes from vertex $1$ across $2$ and ends on vertex $3$

Comment: That isn't a spanning tree of $H$, since it has isolated vertices-the interior vertices on the path between 1 and 3.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe You're right. I missed that, If $G=K_3$ then for every spanning tree of $G$ there are $3$ spanning trees in $H$ and answer is $t(H)=3\cdot t(G)$. But i don't really see how this helps.  You think maybe $$t(H)=3^c(G)}t(G)$$ where $c(G)$ is number of cycles?

Comment: So in the general case, can you associate spanning trees of $H$ with spanning trees of $G$? Did you try for something a little more complicated, maybe $K_4$ or $K_4-e$ ($K_4$ with one edge deleted) and $k=30$?

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe So now i think the answer involving $m$ number of edges, $n$ number of vertices $$t(H)=t(G)\cdot k^{m-(n-1)}$$

Comment: And now prove it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question. I make Computer simulations: https://github.com/miaosiSari/spanningtree and simulate three cases: (1) $K_n$(2) $K_{m,n}$(3) random graph. Feel free to report a bug!

Currently I am unable to deduce a closed-form solution. It is hard to use the formula $t(G) = t(G \cdot e) + t(G - e)$ here because you have to shrink "too many" edges. You may consider special cases first, e.g., complete or $n$-parite graphs. Or, you may try using computer programs to simulate more situations.